# In R how to you modify a logistic regression where the cost of selecting one of the classes is much higher than the other.

Tags: r, regression, logistic

Say I have the following in R

```
rm(list=ls())
set.seed(1000)
n<-20
x<-rnorm(n, 0.5,1)
y<-rnorm(n, 0.5,1)
type<-rep(2,n)
df1<-data.frame(x,y,type)
x<-rnorm(n, -0.5,1)
y<-rnorm(n, -0.5,1)
type<-rep(5,n)
df0<-data.frame(x,y,type)
df<-merge(x=df0,y=df1,all=T)
plot(df$x,df$y,col=df$type)
```

[image]

Now as you can see I have classes that overlap -- say the cost of classifying the red class incorrectly is 10 times the cost of classifying  the blue class incorrectly.

Say I want to use a logistic regression -- how would I do incorporate the cost into my logistic regression model?

Comment: Why would you incorporate the cost in the model at all?  Doesn't cost relate to the question of *sample design* when you are prospectively contemplating obtaining data?  If not, then could you elaborate on what these costs actually reflect?

Comment: With a logistic regression classifier, usually one chooses a threshold to dichotomize predictions into positive and negative. Are you asking for a way to incorporate this cost into finding an optimal threshold or are you hoping to obtain another binary classifier altogether?

Comment: @whuber, I guess that was my question -- is the cost function solely employed on the probabilities the model spits out when scoring?